# Working on SSRS report - page break issue - SSRS 2016

Tags: reporting-services

I have a main report that runs 4 sub reports that I could not get the report to break on the DailyJobID that I needed.  So, I created another main report to run the Main report, now called Main-Sub and tried to get it to do a page break on the DailyJobID.  So far I have not been able to get this report to break properly, it sounds simple.

My stored procedures select data for a job, for a person, then for multiple dates.  I get the correct data in my parameters, my stored procedures bring back the correct data based on the parameters and the DailyJobID for each job is included in each dataset.

Instead of separate reports it puts all data for the job on one report, and then breaks and places the same data on the second report also.

I have tried rectangles, using a list instead of a tablix, but nothing changes.  I've tried this on both the main and the main sub report.

I am grouping on the DailyJobID, on the Main Report and the main Sub report.  I've changed the grouping to group using another series of fields, like jobnumber and date, but it does not change anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show with images what is happening and mock up what you want it to do? It's not very clear what you are wanting!